# CodeIgniter does not load html5 views correctly

Tags: html, continuous-integration

well, when I load my view in CI here is what has been rendered in the browser

here is the code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        the DOCTYPE tag does not appear,
        html5 does not render correctly
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image: html5 error]

I hope I find a fix for this issue

thanks in advance